# SELECT by certain bytes of a binary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Is there a way to perform something like the following SELECT?

```
SELECT * FROM TheTable WHERE 3rd_to_5th_bytes_of_column_A  = 0x010101;
```

And if there's a serious performance issue - please let me know. This is to be a new table.

(Of course I can load all of the data and search it in my C# application. I mean - is there a direct way.)

**Due to comments:** If the data in that row in that column is: **0x010203040506** , the row will not be selected. But if the data is **0x010201010106** - it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING` function - it also works on binary/varbinary/image columns.

```
SELECT * FROM TheTable WHERE SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 2, 3) = 0x010101
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: Index cannot not be used if the SUBSTRING does not start at position 0 (not sure if it will be used even then). Also note that index key size cannot exceed 900 bytes so you cannot index large binary columns.

Comment: If you're answering my previous comment - What I meant was: Will this be very slow?

Comment: @ispiro Well, that depends, how many rows are we talking about? What is the actual size of the column? If this 3rd-5th byte portion of the string is important, why not store it separately?

Comment: @AaronBertrand There are reasons for storing this way, such as what will be done with the data later. As for how many rows and columns - Why would that matter? As always - the more - the slower, of course. But that's always true. (I am thinking, though, of making it a fixed length binary as opposed to a varbinary, so I hope the server will be able to go right to the correct information.)

Comment: @ispiro Well you can always created a persisted computed column and index it - so that when you want to go after the substring, you can do it using a seek or range scan, and when you want to go after the whole value, you can. Why does it matter how many rows (I didn't ask how many columns, but rather the width of the column, which influences how many rows fit on a page)? Because if you have 1000 rows you are unlikely to see any performance difference no matter what you do, and none of the options will be "very slow." If you have 10 billion rows, on the other hand...

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also use the Sql Server [Bitwise Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx)

```
select * from TheTable where myColumn >= @myMask
    and myColumn & @myMask <> 0
```

The DRY violation is per [When the DRY principle doesn’t apply](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/dry-principle), which offers a significant performance improvement over a more conventional `where myColumn & @myMaxk <> 0`.

The problem occurs because performing a bitwise operation prevents use of an index.

Comment: You meant that just to get me started, right? It seems I'll have to mask, shift, and then check if it's equal to what I'm looking for. (Also, Do you have any idea if this will be very slow?)

Comment: I haven't used the SQL Bitwise operators, but in general that sort of operation is pretty quick.  You'll have to do some testing.